# Oracle USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST filesystem path

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, rman, archive-log

As stated in [oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/archredo.htm#ADMIN11337)

> - The keyword USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST to indicate the Fast Recovery Area

I know it's setted during `dbca` but how can identify the `Fast Recovery Area` filesystem path on a running Oracle12c instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SQL> show parameter db_recovery_file_dest

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
db_recovery_file_dest                string      +O71_FRA
db_recovery_file_dest_size           big integer 8G
```

Comment: Thank you! [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-59C29B1D-8536-4C43-B999-46CC5F61F430.htm#ADMQS12106) I found also `select * from v$recovery_file_dest;` that I think it's the same.